# How to implement Front Controller with Spring MVC 3.0

Tags: spring-mvc

I used to use javax.servlet.Filter to handle some process such as authentication and character encoding. Is there something in Spring MVC 3.0 like Filter, handling request before other controllers handle it.(a front controller) And also, it is able to be injected the dependencies by constructor or setters. For example,

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public String getHomePage() {
        return "home";
    }
}

public class Authentication {

    private Foo foo;

    public void setFoo(Foo foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    // filter the url "/home"
    public String authenticate() {
        if (foo.authenticated()) {
            return toHomeController;
        }
        return toErrorController;
    }
}
```

Before handling the request from /home or other urls, the user should be authorized. If not, he should be redirected to other url, such as /error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I used to use javax.servlet.Filter to handle some process such as authentication and character encoding.

All of this already exists in Spring:

- use [Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/) for authentication/authorization
- use [CharacterEncodingFilte](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/CharacterEncodingFilter.html) for character encoding

> Is there something in Spring MVC 3.0 like Filter, handling request before other controllers handle it.(a front controller)

Yes, Spring has [DispatcherServlet](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.html) who does exactly this.

> And also, it is able to be injected the dependencies by constructor or setters.

Yes, Spring will do it for you.

You can start from [Spring Reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/):

- Read about [Spring IoC](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/)
- Read about [Web MVC framework](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html)

Comment: What I really want to do is to implement something that is not authentication and character encoding but like how they work.

Comment: Hm... probably `DelegatingFilterProxy` might help to you: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/DelegatingFilterProxy.html